# How to play AVI video file that contains MJPG format on iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avi, mjpeg

I have AVI file that contains MJPG 640x480 [V: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 640x480] with the duration 1 minute. AVPlayer can not play this avi file. I always see the endless progress indicator. How can I play this file on iOS?

Comment: Are you sure iOS can handle AVI containers?

Comment: Method  AVURLAsset.audiovisualTypes() contains value "public.avi"

Comment: AVI containers may be incompatible with that kind of player as AVI is a quirky Microsoft format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [MobileVLCKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MobileVLCKit) to play video. This Player was able to play the AVI format.